# Cocos2D not updating after view popped and pushed

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, cocos2d-iphone

I'm writing an iPhone game which has a number of levels. During play the user can use a menu to quit the game and return to the level select screen. To do this I'm using a UINavigationController with series of UIViewControllers. When the player chooses to quit, the game view is popped from the stack and the level select menu is displayed. The game runs fine the first time through but if the player quits the level and then tries to play the same or another level this causes a problem.

The game view controller (which displays the cocos2d scene) is a member variable of a game controller singleton. When the user clicks "play again" this game controller resets the game state. The cocos2d layers are cleared and the game is reset to it's starting condition. After this the game view is pushed onto the stack again. This time however cocos2d doesn't update. The screen is just the last frame from the previous game frozen.

It seems that for some reason when the cocos2d view is popped and then pushed it stops updating even though I use:

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] resume];
```

Does anyone have any experience of this problem and how it could be avoided?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your game view controller is popped the `[[CCDirector sharedDirector] stopAnimation]` is called, so after pushing your game view controller onto the stack again you must call the `[[CCDirector sharedDirector] startAnimation]`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've been trying to figure out why a cocos2d glview would work ok in a single view app but not inside a navigation controller's view. This fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would try it like that:

```
[self resumeSchedulerAndActions];
    for(CCSprite *sprite in [self children]) {
        [[CCActionManager sharedManager] resumeTarget:sprite];
    }
```